# CodeIgniter custom validation overrides core validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I need a specific rule for a form input of mine, so I extended the library like so :

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    function __construct($config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
    //.............
}
```

So that worked for me just fine, however now I am noticing that if the validation function for example this one :

```
public function is_sentence($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-?._ -]+$/", $str))// Alpha, Int, Basic Punctuation, Hyphens, Underscores, Spaces
        {
            $this -> set_message('is_sentence', 'The %s field can only contain letters, digits, spaces, dashes and periods.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Indeed `return TRUE` (meaning that it only contains sentence characters) the validation will pass the run() from CodeIgniter but other forms that are will fail. This is where the issue begins in that, the set_value() function from the form_helper does not work any more leaving the input field using the **is_sentence rule** empty.

This is my first time ever extending this library, and I just can't get passed this issue.

So just summarize :

if using a custom validation function, if validation fails for all other form inputs except the custom validation one the set_value() for the custom validation does not echo any more.

Now if I purposefully cause a error in validation for is_sentence then the set_value() works as expected!

As well, with other form_inputs using the default validation rules ('interger' - for example) this anomaly does not happen.

I'm stumped, any help would be so very much appreciated.

Comment: In general, you don't extend this lib. You have callbacks if you want to write your own specific rules. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Comment: That's not true - you use callbacks for specific controllers; you extend if you need an app-wide function added

Comment: You are not returning TRUE when it passes is_sentence() - is this a typo, or in your code? It should be there

Comment: @jmadsen thats exactly what the problem was. I fixed it yesterday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The isssue that I was having was the I wansn't returning true. fixed it like so :

```
public function is_sentence($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9-?._ -]+$/", $str))// Alpha, Int, Basic Punctuation, Hyphens, Underscores, Spaces
        {
            $this -> set_message('is_sentence', 'The %s field can only contain letters, digits, spaces, dashes and periods.');
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```